# How to deploy Yii and Django together

Tags: django, .htaccess, yii

I have a yii site. But I want to have django to serve the pages that that have url path
www.mysite.com/django or in subdomain www.django.mysite.com  The sever has fastcgi installed and it is a shared server.

My .htaccess file for yii looks like this (it is in www folder) as I have removed index.php for clean url

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
`   IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

By shared server do mean a paid host? The real question is do you have access to the apache conf, and if not can you ask the host politely to insert a VirtualHost for you for django.